# what is the ip of hiveserver2 in CDH quickstart vm?

Tags: beeline

How to establish a connection with the hiveserver2 using jdbc connectivity with Beeline? What ip address should be used to connect?

Answer (score 0):

This blog post is a little bit dated but still relevant:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/02/migrating-from-hive-cli-to-beeline-a-primer/